# Add a new pair to an existing Hash

Tags: ruby

I need somehow to add value:
`sizes = { :thumb => ["100x100"] }`
to an existing Hash.

The problem is, that the meaning `:thumb` comes as a variable, so making

```
sizes[@thumb] = ["100x100"] 
# or 
sizes.merge!(@thumb=>["100x100"]) 

# the result is:
> sizes = { "thumb" => ["100x100"] }
```

In my App `"thumb"` isn't accepted. It need to provide `:thumb` key format. How could I make this?

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with `Hash`es. Do you want to know how to convert a `String` to a `Symbol`?

Comment: I needed to convert string with .to_sym, otherwise it doesn't work for some specific functions. Thanks for @saurabh for noticing the difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
sizes[@thumb.to_sym] = ["100x100"] 
# or
sizes.merge!(@thumb.to_sym => ["100x100"])
```